# How do i make a cloth simulation but make parts of it hold it in place like a cape

Tags: armature, cloth-simulation

So i know the most basic parts of making a cloth simulation but how do i make parts of the model stay in one place while the rest hangs freely?

Im still new to blender and am learning loads of new things. The tutorials i've seen don't cover what im looking for. I should also add that the model has a pre-made armature as im porting from a game.

Comment: You need to create a vertex group where the cloth is supposed to hang, then in the Physics > Cloth > Shape > Pin Group, select this group. If you want some vertices to be half hanging, just half assign them to this group... video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=187&v=S4hCnbakm6g

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a vertex group where the cloth is supposed to hang, then in the *Physics* > *Cloth* > *Shape* > *Pin Group*, select this group. If you want some vertices to be half hanging, select them, decrease the weight you want to assign and press *Assign*.

[image]